# Cyclic Quadrilateral with an equilateral triangle as a part of it

Tags: triangles, circles, quadrilateral

Find the relation between RX, RY and RZ if XYZ is an equilateral triangle.

[image]

Comment: Please show your work

Comment: How far have you gotten on the question? Where do you get stuck? Where does the question come from? What do you know about quadrilaterals inscribed in circles?

Comment: All I know is that it is a HOTS question for a 9th grader. And Cyclic quadrilaterals have their opposite angles supplementary.

Comment: What is a "HOTS question", please?

Comment: I say, WHAT IS A *HOTS* QUESTION, PLEASE?

Comment: Higher Order Thinking Skills - HOTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation:
Let the intersection of XR and YZ be O.
∠XRY = ∠XRZ

∠ORY = ∠XRZ
∠RYZ = ∠RXZ
Therefore, Triangle YOR is similar to Triangle XZR.
=> XZ.YR = OY.XR --(1)

∠XRY = ∠ORZ
∠YXR = ∠YZR
Therefore, Triangle ZOR is similar to Triangle XYR.
=> XY.ZR = OZ.XR --(2)

Adding (1) and (2)
XZ.YR + XY.ZR = OY.XR + OZ.XR
=> XY(YR + ZR) = XR.YZ
=> RY + RZ = RX
Thus Proved.

Answer (score 1):

Ptolemy's Theorem says that $RX.YZ=RY.XZ+RZ.YX$.

Since $XY=YZ=ZX$, this simplifies to $RX=RY+RZ$.

Comment: This is correct and easy to do. But will a 9th grader do this?

Comment: You can prove it using similar triangles but it is not that easy.

Comment: I've now added the easiest proof I can think of.

Comment: I've added the solution which I found.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the cosine rule for the triangles XYR and XZR to establish relationship among RX, RY and RZ. (keep in mind ∠XRY = ∠XRZ)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer not using Ptolemy**

Angle $XRZ=60^o$ by angle on a chord. So, by the cosine rule:

$XZ^2=XR^2+RZ^2-XR.RZ$ and, similarly

$XY^2=XR^2+RY^2-XR.RY$.

Subtracting

$RZ^2-XR.RZ=RY^2-XR.RY$

$RZ^2-RY^2=XR.RZ-RX.RY$

$(RZ-RY)(RZ+RY)=RX(RZ-RY)$

So $RX=RY+RZ$ or $RY=RZ$.

The case  $RY=RZ$ produces a simple configuration which also gives $RX=RY+RZ$.